# Thread 1 SIGABRT

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to follow along with the iTunes U course coding together, which covers Objective C. When I compile the first code, it builds with no errors, but when it runs, i get an error that says Thread 1: SIGABRT. in the main file

```
 //
//  main.m
//  Card
//
//  Created by Sid Muthal on 6/25/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 SidMuthal. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "CardGameAppDelegate.h"

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([CardGameAppDelegate    class]));
}
}
```

It appears over the line that reads return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([CardGameAppDelegate class]));

When I use the GDB debugger, it gives the following reason for this crash

2013-07-14 14:08:46.052 Matchgame[3148:c07] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Card_button.' * First throw call stack: (0x1c94012 0x10d1e7e 0x1d1cfb1 0xb7de41 0xaff5f8 0xaff0e7 0xb29b58 0x233019 0x10e5663 0x1c8f45a 0x231b1c 0xf67e7 0xf6dc8 0xf6ff8 0xf7232 0x463d5 0x4676f 0x46905 0xcd6eab6 0x4f917 0x1396c 0x1494b 0x25cb5 0x26beb 0x18698 0x1befdf9 0x1befad0 0x1c09bf5 0x1c09962 0x1c3abb6 0x1c39f44 0x1c39e1b 0x1417a 0x15ffc 0x20ed 0x2015) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

It appears to be something wrong with my View controller. Below is the code that I am using for the Game controller.

```
//
//  CardGameViewController.m
//  Card
//
//  Created by Sid Muthal on 6/25/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 SidMuthal. All rights reserved.
//

    #import "CardGameViewController.h"

@interface CardGameViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *flipsLabel;
@property(nonatomic) int flipCount;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *cardButton;
@end

@implementation CardGameViewController

    -(void)setFlipCount:(int)flipCount
{
    _flipCount = flipCount;
    self.flipsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Flips: %d", self.flipCount];

}

    - (IBAction)flipCard:(UIButton *)sender
{
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
    self.flipCount++;
}

@end
```

Below is the h file.

```
//
//  CardGameViewController.h
//  Card
//
//  Created by Sid Muthal on 6/25/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 SidMuthal. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CardGameViewController: UIViewController


@end
```

Ive been struggling with this for a while so any help would be much appreciated. I'm still new to Objective C. Thank you.

Comment: u need to learn how to debug it , you will need to add the breakpoint to see more meaningful information about the error

Comment: I think you linked the cardButton incorrectly in interface builder/storyboard. Is there something like 'Card_button' ? You should probably link 'cardButton'.

Comment: MartinE. is correct. In interface builder, right click on the file's owner and you will see a link with a yellow exclamation. Delete that one and it should work.

Comment: "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Card_button.' " That's the key to solve the bug, it may be a matter of 2 minutes if you know where to look.

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but will help you debug: It's a generic breakpoint to catch all exceptions: http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you did not delete the first button's Outlet after you changed it to an Outlet Collection (deleting/changing just the code is not enough).
To do that just right click (or CTRL+click) on the first button and delete the Outlet under "Referencing Outlets" and that should fix it.